# localhost tesing oAuth - Yahoo, MSN, Hotmail, Facebook

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I know that there are many questions like this, but most seem to be older.
I know all about setting up my web app on the above services, and have seen that most require a valid domain for a callback [www.abc.com/oauthReturn.aspx].
What do I need to do in order to test locally, where the return URL would be: http://localhost:0000/oauthReturn.aspx ? 
You can't use http://127.0.0.1 in Yahoo - not a valid URL. 
I'm running asp.net/VB.net, IIS7. Localhost runs Windows 7 & Prod server runs Windows 2008 server. 
When I try accessing the microsoft site, I get an error message, after I sign in, about not allowing localhost. 
 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanx
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

Try [following the instructions here](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2009/08/17/how-to-quickly-set-up-a-test-for-twitter-oauth-authentication-from-your-local-machine/). Make sure to read all the way to the bottom where they suggest registering the localhost call back URL in bit.ly (or some other URL shortener) and using the bit.ly link as the call back URL.

Comment: Will definitely look into this...Do you think some of the services I mentioned above check the 'return url' that gets passed back w/the return url defined when the app was created?  Do you think I'd have to pass the bit.ly url?  In the meantime - THANX!!!

Comment: MarK:  So far, so good...was indedd able to create the call back url's, but had to use goog.gl instead of bit.ly...Will be testing the results tonite...

Comment: Really thought the goo.gl url shortener was going to work.  I guess some of the services mentioned above append a return querystring to the callback URL & it seems that once the goo.gl URL is processed, the querystring was dropped...

Comment: Try para.ms as a url shortener. I haven't used it, but they claim to allow parameters.